# Drupal - Zen Subtheme - Specify stylesheets for non-Internet Explorer browsers

Tags: drupal, themes, stylesheet

On Drupal 6 using a Zen subtheme, our custom stylesheet is beautiful and perfect everywhere except in Internet Explorer 7. It appears to be the `:hover` bug, where any link we hover over causes the main content area to jump over the left sidebar (is that called margin collapse or margin reset?).

Tried setting min-height: 1% on all `:hover` and parent elements, but there are soooo many finally decided to specify an 'ie7specific.css' which has zero hover elements defined. Tough luck for Internet Explorer 7 users.

However, in the `myspecialsub_theme.info` file the `myspecialsub_theme.css` is automatically sent to Internet Explorer, therefore creating the `:hover` elements. We need to specify Internet Explorer 7 gets its specific CSS and all other browsers get the regular.

```
conditional-stylesheets[if gt IE 7][all][] = myspecialsub_theme.css
conditional-stylesheets[if IE 7][all][] = ie7specific.css
conditional-stylesheets[if lt IE 7][all][] = myspecialsub_theme.css
conditional-stylesheets[if !IE][all][] = myspecialsub_theme.css
```

It works for Internet Explorer versions, but Firefox is not getting the stylesheet. Why isn't the !IE working, what should I use instead?

Or is there a different solution for the problem described?

UPDATE:
My comment did not display well below, here is the solution I finally found:

Solution thanks to [wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment).

In the `subtheme.info`:

```
; stylesheets[all][] = specific_subtheme.css
conditional-stylesheets[if gt IE 7][all][] = specific_subtheme.css
conditional-stylesheets[if IE 7][all][] = ie7specific.css
conditional-stylesheets[if lt IE 7][all][] = specific_subtheme.css
```

In `page.tpl.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>">
<head>
    <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <?php print $head; ?>
    <?php print $styles; ?>
    <![if !IE]>
        <link href="/sites/all/themes/specific_subtheme/specific_subtheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]>
    <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
```

Crazy huh?

FINAL UPDATE: Best yet, I finally discovered the source of `:hover` bug in the Zen subtheme. The div main needs a `zoom:1;` and none of these conditional stylesheets are necessary. But there you go if you cannot solve the original problem.

Comment: Found solution, thanks to wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment
In the subtheme.info:
    ; stylesheets[all][] = specific_subtheme.css
    conditional-stylesheets[if gt IE 7][all][] = specific_subtheme.css
    conditional-stylesheets[if IE 7][all][] = ie7specific.css
    conditional-stylesheets[if lt IE 7][all][] = specific_subtheme.css
In page.tpl.php:
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <?php print $head; ?>
    <?php print $styles; ?>
    <![if !IE]>
    <link href="/sites/all/themes/specific_subtheme/specific_subtheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:
Just realized I can answer my own questions. Not seeking reputation points, but want to clarify the right solution for anyone else looking into this.

Solution thanks to wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

In the subtheme.info:

```
; stylesheets[all][] = specific_subtheme.css
conditional-stylesheets[if gt IE 7][all][] = specific_subtheme.css
conditional-stylesheets[if IE 7][all][] = ie7specific.css
conditional-stylesheets[if lt IE 7][all][] = specific_subtheme.css
```

In page.tpl.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>">
<head>
<title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<?php print $head; ?>
<?php print $styles; ?>
<![if !IE]>
<link href="/sites/all/themes/specific_subtheme/specific_subtheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]>
<?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
```

Crazy huh?

AAAAND btw finally fixed the hover selector/collapsing margin bug in IE7, using the drupal zen theme, in IE pasting

```
javascript:alert(content.currentStyle.hasLayout)
```

into the location bar and hitting enter, would tell me if the id=content element hasLayout (true or false). I kept replacing content with other id names like main-inner, primary, until I discovered main div was false. Adding a property of zoom:1; to that ie7specific.css cured all the problems.

God bless Microsoft.

Comment: I found that I needed to disable the default conditional comment styles in zen.info, to be able to use the conditional comment styles defined in MYTHEME.info.

Answer (score 0):

!IE won't work as I understand it because only IE supports conditional stylesheets.

The way I handle this is to define the other browsers stuff in the main stylesheet and override as needed in the IE conditionals.

You could do this:

```
 stylesheets[all][] = myspecialsub_theme.css
 conditional-stylesheets[if IE 7][all][] = ie7specific.css
```

Of course the IE specific stuff will need to do extra work to override any stuff that wouldn't otherwise have been imported but thats what you get for using IE.

Comment: ack! yeah that ie7 :hover bug is the problem, if ie7 gets the original stylesheet with the numerous :hover declarations then I cannot override them, I have to then add min-height declarations to all those and parent elements, which is a huge pain. any other ideas to prevent IE from seeing original style sheet but ensure other browsers get it?

Comment: Only nasty ones like using conditional comments to add an extra class somewhere and use jquery to attach or remove the hover, or using a existing js solution or if you hate caching and want your site to run slow you could even detect it in PHP, feel dirty now

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement statements need to print like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/style.css" 
type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/ie7.css" 
type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <![endif]-->
```

Remember to place the IE tag after your normal CSS so that you can over write the IE issues.

Also, I wouldn't wrap your main stylesheet in a conditional statement:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<h1>You are NOT using Internet Explorer</h1>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Just target IE7 with you first fix and be done.

Cheers!

Comment: I really appreciate help but still no go. I tried a few weeks ago and again now in my ie7specific.css to 'reset' the hover styles to be exactly like the a element. It still fails causing the content to jump left when link is hovered. I think this has to do with the notorious hasLayout setting getting set in the first original css, then there is no way to 'unset' it in ie7specific.css. To be clear, I changed my css to deliver regular css to all, then the conditional ie7 to deliver just the ie7specific.css after. Still broken because the :hover elements in the regular css is already in play.

Answer (score 0):

As ben says, you should try overriding the `:hover` selector in `ie7specific.css` with `.selector:hover{property:none}`. Make sure to match every selector and set every property to its regular value. If it still does not work, I think a lighter workaround would be to write those `:hover` or other non-Internet Explorer specifics in a separate file, and load them through JavaScript after detecting the browser. Try http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support.